# Maple 2019 does not evaluate trigonometric functions as functions!

Tags: trigonometry, maple

I need to calculate a function of $\tanh(x)$ in Maple.
The problem is that when I enter my function (or any other trigonometric functions) in Maple, the answer looks like this:

`tanh(x/sqrt(6));
                         -116                      -116
      2.73949338633639 10     + 2.73949338633639 10     I
sin(x);
                         -116                      -116
      2.73949338633639 10     + 2.73949338633639 10     I`

There is no problem with polynomial functions like `x^2+x^5`!

Comment: This is not the place for Maple problems

Comment: It appears that Maple is telling you that these values are *exceedingly* close to (complex) zero. Have you assigned `x` to be a tiny value?

Comment: No I have not assigned any value to x

Comment: Do you have any packages active? Otherwise, what happens if you try `unassign('x'): sin(x)`?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when the Maple kernel thinks that its license authentication has been cracked.

There have been some known cases where this detection is a false positive. The latest point-release Maple 2019.2.1 should be better, with respect to that.

Point-release upgrades are downloadable (free) from www.maplesoft.com

If you have a valid license, and are using the latest point-release for your version, and still encounter the problem then contact support@maplesoft.com

Your question is not about mathematics, per se, and so is off-topic in this forum.

Comment: If this is the underhanded way Maple has been set up to combat (assumed) piracy, it's very wrong.